# In which order are delete voters shown?

Tags: support, review, sorting, vote-to-delete, post-notices

When a post is deleted, a banner is shown indicating which users voted to delete the post:

[image]

[image]

What determines the order in which these users are shown? Often, it seems to be a chronological order (like close votes); it's rare to see a ♦ moderator at any position other than the last one. However, in the first case, [I was the last one to vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/70702) while my name is displayed second. This might be because of the user IDs: 282094 < 295232 < 310650 < 338924 < 398063 < 622284. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349608/295232) is a similar situation with increasing user IDs. Is this a peculiarity of the deletion being a result of a completed six-users-involving Low Quality Posts review task? I found [a situation on Boardgames.SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMG8K.png) where it was completed by four users (three of them trusted) and there they're shown chronologically.

Comment: Might be random, can you check other cases just to verify?

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349889/369802) where the mod also comes last, and it seems the user IDs are in order of votes. I didn't delete that one from the LQP queue. And [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349621/369802) may be interesting too: Deleted via LQP, undeleted by owner, then redeleted by a moderator yet the LQP reviewers are showing up, out of 'voting' order, as having deleted it.

Comment: I think the only times I've seen them out of order of time they voted is if it is deleted with Recommend Delete votes rather than a vote to delete so from within the LQP review.

Comment: Follow-up question and feature request: [Why is there an inconsistency in the display order of delete voters? Can it be made consistent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367542/278659)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Having reviewed a fair number of Low Quality Posts here on Meta SE, I think I can provide enough examples to answer this properly.

First, it's important to recognize that, when a post is deleted via Low Quality Post review, there are two outcomes. I'll refer to these as **Review Conclusions**.

**Recommended Deletion**: The post is deleted because six users chose "Recommend Deletion." This displays as a "post deleted from review" event in the timeline.

**Trusted User Deletion**: Three [trusted level users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (or, at some point, one ♦ moderator) choose "Delete," or the post in total has the required amount of delete votes to cause deletion. This deletion event is given the reason "via Vote" in the timeline.

Moving onto how these votes are displayed in the post notice, barring when the Community ♦ user deletes a post for having too many red flags... There are a few scenarios:

1. Six recommend deletion votes successfully delete a post. These six users are displayed by order of their User ID.
2. Three delete votes (or any number of delete votes and a ♦ moderator deletion) successfully deletes a post. The users who voted to delete are displayed chronologically.
3. A mixture of recommend deletion votes and trusted user delete votes results in Recommended Deletion. All who contributed to this conclusion will be displayed in the post notice by order of their User ID.
4. A mixture of recommend deletion votes and trusted user delete votes results in Trusted User deletion. Only trusted user's names will be displayed, and they are ordered chronologically.

I've catalogued some examples that back up these observations, and I'll list them below.

---

#### Example 1

**Review Conclusion - Recommended Deletion**

The User ID's of the following deletion are displayed numerically. The User ID's are 188189 > 286501 > 398063 > 402142 > 622284.

[image: Recommended Deletion]

---

#### Example 2

**Review Conclusion - Trusted User Deletion**

The User ID's of the following delete-voters are displayed 262823 > 158100 > 295232. The conclusion is that they are displayed chronologically.

Notice how the users who chose "Recommend Deletion" aren't displayed. Their votes don't particularly matter in the event of Trusted User deletion (your work reviewing is much appreciated, though!)

[image: Trusted user deletion]

---

#### Example 3

**Review Conclusion - Recommended Deletion**

Lastly, here's where the mixture of delete votes and recommended deletion votes end in a **Recommended Deletion** review completion event.

The User ID's are 188189 > 286501 > 295232 > 383809 > 389791 > 622284.

[image: Trusted and Recommend Deletion votes]

---

#### Overall Conclusion

Trusted User deletions result in a chronological post notice display. Moderators will always appear at the end of this list because they'll always be the last users to vote before a post is deleted (binding vote).

Recommended Deletion results in a post notice displaying the users who recommended deletion by order of their User ID.

Comment: Could very well be due to how their DB queries are organized. Delete votes are stored as votes and thus are easier to access. Review results may (just guessing) be harder (requires more joins) so they've chosen to simply order by ID.

Comment: @iBugathome Yep, it seems that the system doesn't know *when* those "Recommend Deletion" choices are made, only who made them, and it just orders them by user ID. On the flip side, delete votes are actually "votes" in a way, and the time at which they are cast must be tracked.

Comment: For sure the time at which reviews are made are stored. It's probably only that the devs decided that joining the review results table just for ordering names would be too expensive.

Comment: This is quite a well-researched answer for someone who doesn't even have the privilege to view deleted posts. Well done! (And don't worry, you'll be there soon enough.)