# Order by which the users close a question

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions

Suppose that some question from some Stack Exchange site gets closed. Then the user who posted the question as well as any user with close/reopen votes privilege can see a message explaining why the question got closed, followed by “Closed [some time] ago by” and the names of the users who voted to close the question.

I have always assumed that these names appear by the same order by which those votes were cast. Am I right?

Comment: _"I have always assumed that these names appear by the same order that the votes were cast."_ As far I can see, that's the case, yes.

Comment: Related: [In which order are delete voters shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350142/289905).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the order the names appear in the post notice is the order in which the close voters voted to close.

The author actually [no longer sees (see the update)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/622284) who voted to close their question in the post notice. They can still see them via the revision history or the timeline, though.

Here's a screenshot of how a closed question of mine appears to me, as proof of this ([timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/349781/timeline)):

[image: A post notice without close voters shown to the author (me).]

Close voters are also displayed chronologically in the revision history and the timeline. So, too, are reopen voters when a post is reopened.

The only event that I'm aware of in which users aren't displayed chronologically in a post notice like this is during a "Recommended Deletion" event when an answer is deleted via LQP review. I dive deeper into this subject in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350149/622284).

Comment: How does this make sense? If you have close/reopen vote privileges you see *more* information (all of the names) about other people's closed questions than you do about your own. Why would the question author have information withheld (from the notice anyway) if it's their own question, but not if it's somebody else's?

Comment: @JasonBassford as a guess, the people who closed a question are frequently "called out" (or worse) by the question author. The tiny bit of obscurity to the close voters cac likely provide at least a bit of relief from the usual "why did you close my awesome and perfect question?!" and similar comments directed at them. I'm not sure why this information is hidden from question askers who actually have a close vote privilege themselves, though. *Usually* it's expected those users to be more responsible.

Comment: @JasonBassford That is explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/332502/6) by a dev in a response to the request for this feature.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Nice find, I was hunting for that earlier. I'm editing that into this answer.