# Why is there an inconsistency in the display order of delete voters? Can it be made consistent?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

When an answer is deleted, not by the answer poster themselves or by the Community bot, the users who contributed to deleting the answer are shown in the following order:

- **If the post was deleted by Trusted Users and/or a moderator**, the delete voters are shown in the order that they voted. This is regardless of whether said users cast their votes directly on the post or via the review queue. If some lower-rep users also Recommended Deletion via the review queue, their votes are not shown on the final deleted post, only those of the Trusted Users and/or moderator who were enough to get it deleted.
- **Otherwise, if the post was deleted just by review queue votes**, the delete voters are shown in order of their user IDs. This usually means people between 2k and 20k rep (or between 1k and 4k on beta sites) clicking Recommend Deletion from the review queue, but it also includes Trusted Users if between 1 and 3 of them also voted to Delete through the review queue and the post never picked up enough direct Delete votes to be deleted by Trusted Users alone.

The criteria are a bit complicated, but basically **direct deletion** (from delete votes by privileged users) means **vote order**, while **review deletion** (from the review queue without enough privileged users) means **user-ID order**. See [In which order are delete voters shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350142/278659) (with some extra detail added from my own experience).

The above-linked meta post established that there *is* an inconsistency in the order. My question is, **why?** And please **can the order be made consistent?** To me, it would make sense to always list the deleters in the order that their votes were cast; this would also be consistent with the way close and reopen and undelete votes are shown (including close and reopen votes cast through the review queue, to maintain the imperfect analogy with Recommend Deletion votes).

Comment: The "deleted via review" notice was practically just tacked onto the system without much effort to integrate it well. There are some bugs with it, specifically that if an answer is deleted from review, then undeleted, then deleted again by trusted users or a moderator, it will show the prior notice of "deleted via review" with the original reviewers rather than the later voter(s).

Comment: @Sonic Yep, I know - [I posted that bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290623/278659) :-)

Comment: I've [also filed that report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336092/answers-deleted-via-review-then-undeleted-then-re-deleted-by-a-moderator-still), but my report covers regular mod deletions, while yours covers mod comment conversions.